# How to separate overlapping results of WHERE clauses in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by, where-in

I'm searching for multiple people by finding matching names in a table using multiple WHERE clause criteria and then sort the results based on the order in which the names appear in the WHERE clause, something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE table.NAME LIKE '%Alice%' OR
      table.NAME LIKE '%Bob%' OR
      table.NAME LIKE '%Charlie%'
ORDER BY CASE
         WHEN table.NAME LIKE '%Alice%' THEN 1
         WHEN table.NAME LIKE '%Bob%' THEN 2
         WHEN table.NAME LIKE '%Charlie%' THEN 3
         ELSE 4
         END
```

My problem with this is that if I accidentally search for the same name twice (having overlapping results) mySQL only returns the record once which messes up my data ordering and later post processing. For example the following query returns results for Alice, Bob and Charlie in order whereas I would need it to return results for Alice, Bob, Alice, Charlie in order even if the results for the two Alices are the same.

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE table.NAME LIKE '%Alice%' OR
      table.NAME LIKE '%Bob%' OR
      table.NAME LIKE '%Alice%' OR
      table.NAME LIKE '%Charlie%'
ORDER BY CASE
         WHEN table.NAME LIKE '%Alice%' THEN 1
         WHEN table.NAME LIKE '%Bob%' THEN 2
         WHEN table.NAME LIKE '%Alice%' THEN 3
         WHEN table.NAME LIKE '%Charlie%' THEN 4
         ELSE 5
         END
```

Is it even possible in SQL to separate the results of each sub query in the WHERE clause? For context, I need to return results into a dataframe in Python using `pandas.read_sql()`. I considered launching separate queries for each name in Python, but it would be really inefficient to do 100 queries instead of one.

Comment: rowno something perhaps. Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Where is Bob number 2 expected to be sorted?

Comment: In the second query, I would want all results for Alice to come first, followed by all results for Bob, then Alice again, then Charlie. I am using Microsoft SQL Management Studio but I am executing the query string in Python and return the result into a dataframe

Comment: And Alice number 3?

Comment: So are you saying you need the rows where the value has `'Alice'` in it twice?

Comment: "*I am using Microsoft SQL Management Studio but I am executing the query string in Python and return the result into a dataframe"* You aren't using SSMS, you're using SQL Server; SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) is just an IDE. it's like answering "I'm using VSCode." when asked "What programming language are you using?"

Comment: I need the search results for Alice to appear twice in the dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL is a set-processing language. Your `FROM whatever WHERE whatever` clauses return a set of rows. Your `ORDER BY` clause sorts that result set into the order you specify.

You are looking for a way for some rows to appear multiple times in the result set. That requires either, as you mention, multiple queries, or it requires UNION ALL.

Something like this may do the trick.

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM (
            SELECT *, 1 order_position FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%Alice%'
            UNION ALL
            SELECT *, 2 order_position FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%Bob%'
            UNION ALL
            SELECT *, 3 order_position FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%Alice%'
       ) r
 ORDER BY order_position
```

Answer (score 1):

You could put the search criteria in a virtual or real table, and join, then order by an ordering column

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM [table] t
  JOIN (VALUES
    (1, '%Alice%'),
    (2, '%Bob%'),
    (3, '%Alice%')
  ) v(order_position, search)
    ON t.name LIKE v.search
ORDER BY v.order_position
```