# Optimizing mySQL query to scale better

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, query-optimization

I want to query a database to retrieve a list of names (the list of names is provided by the user in python). My criteria for looking up data for these names are the following: the results should appear in the order of the list of names the user provided, so if I say `...WHERE name = "Bob" OR name = "Alice"` I want the results for Bob to come first followed by that of Alice. The second criteria is that if there is a search for a name twice, then the result should also contain it twice, so I want a way to write down `...WHERE name = 'Bob' OR name = 'Bob'` so that the result also contains the rows for Bob twice.

I came up with the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM
   (SELECT *, 1 order_position FROM table WHERE name = 'Alice'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *, 2 order_position FROM table WHERE name = 'Bob'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *, 3 order_position FROM table WHERE name = 'Charlie'
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT *, 4 order_position FROM table WHERE name = 'Dan'
   ) r ORDER BY order_position
```

This query works well, but when the user submits hundreds of names and there are hundreds of UNION ALL sections, the query becomes extremely slow. Is there a way to improve the performance of the query while maintaining the two criteria mentioned before?

Comment: This relates to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69644937/how-to-separate-overlapping-results-of-where-clauses-in-sql/69645103#69645103

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT *, CASE name WHEN 'Alice'   THEN 1
                    WHEN 'Bob'     THEN 2
                    WHEN 'Charlie' THEN 3
                    WHEN 'Dan'     THEN 4
                    END AS order_position 
FROM table 
WHERE name IN ('Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie', 'Dan')
ORDER BY order_position;
```

or without additional column:

```
SELECT *
FROM table 
WHERE name IN ('Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie', 'Dan')
ORDER BY CASE name WHEN 'Alice'   THEN 1
                   WHEN 'Bob'     THEN 2
                   WHEN 'Charlie' THEN 3
                   WHEN 'Dan'     THEN 4
                   END;
```

PS. For this names set `ORDER BY name` is enough.

---

> How does this handle the requirement of repeating some results? –
> Willem Renzema

If you need in repeating then you must convert the list to a rowset.

```sql
SELECT table.*
FROM table
JOIN ( SELECT 1 pos, 'Alice'   name UNION ALL
       SELECT 2    , 'Bob'          UNION ALL
       SELECT 3    , 'Charlie'      UNION ALL
       SELECT 4    , 'Bob'          UNION ALL
       SELECT 5    , 'Charlie' ) names USING (name)
ORDER BY names.pos
```

Comment: How does this handle the requirement of repeating some results?

Comment: @WillemRenzema If you need in repeating then you must convert the list to a rowset... wait... done.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow you have to construct the list of names with the `order_position` of each name.
You can do this in a query which uses `UNION ALL` to preserve duplicate names like this:

```
SELECT 'Alice' name, 1 order_position UNION ALL
SELECT 'Bob', 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Charlie', 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Dan', 4 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Alice', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Bob', 2 UNION ALL
...............................
```

Then all you have to do is join it to the table:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM tablename t
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT 'Alice' name, 1 order_position UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Bob', 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Charlie', 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Dan', 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Alice', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Bob', 2 UNION ALL
  ...............................
) n ON n.name = t.name
ORDER BY n.order_position;
```

In MySql 8.0+ you can use a CTE:

```
WITH cte(name, order_position) AS (VALUES 
  ROW('Alice', 1), ROW('Bob', 2), ROW('Charlie', 3), 
  ROW('Dan', 4), ROW('Alice', 1), ROW('Bob', 2),
  ...................................................
)
SELECT t.* 
FROM tablename t INNER JOIN cte c 
ON c.name = t.name
ORDER BY c.order_position;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will be "fast" if `name` is indexed:

```
WHERE name IN             ('Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie', 'Dan')
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(name, 'Alice,Bob,Charlie,Dan')
```

Note the syntax difference between Where and Order.

The following is likely to be somewhat slower because it cannot use any index but is simpler to code:

```
WHERE    FIND_IN_SET(name, 'Alice,Bob,Charlie,Dan')
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(name, 'Alice,Bob,Charlie,Dan')
```

Note the restriction in `FIND_IN_SET` that commas cannot be used in the items.

In no case will `CASE` or `FIND_IN_SET()` use an index.  (Cf "sargable")

**Repeats**

If, say, there are multiple "Bobs", then each of these have exactly the same effect as the above:

```
name IN ('Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie', 'Bob', 'Dan')
FIND_IN_SET(name, 'Alice,Bob,Charlie,Bob,Dan')
```

That is, all the Bobs will be listed in the output before all the Charlies.  Furthermore, no individual row is listed twice.

Comment: You missed this: *if there is a search for a name twice, then the result should also contain it twice*

Comment: @forpas - My suggestion happens to do that.  (I added an explicit note to that effect.)

Comment: *all the Bobs will be listed in the output before all the Charlies* yes but not twice.